# gtkmm and Gtk::Builder: Lifetime of objects after calling get_widget

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I think I must be "doing something wrong" here. I have a program using gtkmm. The main window for the program is a subclass of `Gtk::Window` and I have the bare bones of the application drawn out in Glade.

Here's an edited version of the main window's constructor:

```
template<class T>
static T*
get_widget (Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder, const Glib::ustring& name)
{
    T* widget;
    builder->get_widget (name, widget);
    if (! widget) no_such_widget (name);

    return widget;
}

app_window::app_window ()
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;

    try {
        builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file (installed_ui_name);
    }
    catch (const Glib::FileError& err) {
        g_error ("Couldn't open UI definition file at %s",
                 installed_ui_name);
        throw;
    }

    // main_box is a std::unique_ptr<Gtk::Widget>, a field of app_window.
    //
    // This works fine: the Gtk::Box gets added as the main child of this
    // app_window and survives until the app_window is destroyed.

    main_box.reset (get_widget <Gtk::Box> (builder, "main-box"));
    add (* main_box);

    auto accel_group = get_accel_group ();

    // This doesn't work so well
    //
    // menu_quit is a Gtk::MenuItem*. The object seems to be actually
    // constructed for the call to builder->get_widget, because its existence
    // stops the menu item from being finalized at the end of the application.

    auto menu_quit (get_widget<Gtk::MenuItem> (builder, "menu-quit"));

    menu_quit->add_accelerator ("activate", accel_group,
                                GDK_KEY_q, Gdk::CONTROL_MASK, Gtk::ACCEL_VISIBLE);

    using std::bind;
    menu_quit->signal_activate ().connect (bind (& app_window::on_close, this));

    show ();
}
```

When setting up the window, I want to register various signal handlers for menu items etc. (the `menu_quit` widget in the example is just one of them). To do so, I think I need to use `builder->get_widget()` to get hold of an object to talk about.

The problem is that I've now got an instance of (a subclass of) `Gtk::Widget` and I don't know what to do with it. If I call delete on the pointer, the widget doesn't appear in the application, but no other problems happen. That's a bit confusing: I would expect either no effect or a segmentation fault (depending on whether something else thought it owned the object or not).

If, on the other hand, I leak the pointer, assuming that object will be owned by the container into which main_box has been added, I get a memory leak. In particular, `menu_quit`'s underlying `gtk_image_menu_item` doesn't get finalised because the reference count is one too high. (I can check easily enough that with GDB)

A "solution" is to store a pointer to each object that I get with `builder->get_widget` as a field in the `app_window` and then delete it in the destructor (automated with `std::auto_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`). But that's really horrible: I don't want to have to write out a field for every single menu item! Avoiding that sort of nonsense was the whole point of using `GtkBuilder` in the first place!

Assuming that this isn't a bug (gtkmm 3.12.0, if that's relevant), I assume I'm just doing it wrong. How is an application supposed to do this?

Comment: There is the concept of sunk and unsunk references. My guess is that this is also the case for gtkmm (which I am not very used to). In a nutshell. The widget spawned by the builder only gets a ref when you explicitly ref it or you add it to a container. By default a widget has a unsunk reference, which any ref-func does sink so you get a regular reference. Also you do not have to care much of the lifetime if the reference count is one (it is one, unless you add it to multiple containers or do a explicit ref) and will be killed as soon as its parent is killed. From the back of my head, salt it.

Comment: I am not sure if this hits your nail, but here is an [official documentation link](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-memory.html)

Comment: Thank you. Someone called "hub" on the #c++ channel at irc.gnome.org pointed me to the concept of managed objects in Gtkmm, which also seems to be relevant, but unfortunately things don't work how I expected: Investigating with GDB, I see that the return value of the C Gtk builder function has one reference (good!). Then it gets wrapped into a C++ object with Gtkmm::wrap and gets 2. Ok. Unfortunately, when I destroy the C++ object, the widget seems to be completely destroyed. Most confused, and intend to build a small test case now.

Comment: If you can create a minimal compilable example that reproduces it, I'd be happy to have a deeper look into it.